# Django FormView passing paramaters and context

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I want to return some data based on a pk that is passed in the url, in a FormView, view, my question is, how can I pass in the paramater and define the context?

Comment: Please ask questions along with some code. You can post your existing `views.py`, `forms.py` and `urls.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
class View(FormView)
  ...

  def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    context = super(View, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['data'] = Model.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('some_id'))
    return context
```

Comment: Yes, that would settle the issue witu passing the context, but how could the pk in the paramaters in the url, or that part wpuld be handled in the self.kwargs.get() part?